# How do you diagnose errors with a subscribed calendar in Outlook?

Tags: outlook, office365

For years I have subscribed to my personal Google calendar in my work Outlook so I can see events from both calendars in one place. It recently stopped updating, so I re-added the subscription (via Add Calendar --> from internet in Outlook on the web). But it only pulls in a handful of events from the Google calendar now.

I suspect there's a malformed event somewhere in the 50k line ics file that I get when I export my calendar from Google, but I don't know how to find it. I have noted the following:

- if I subscribe to the "public" Google calendar url with full details shared, I get the same results. If I subscribe to the public url with details hidden, the free/busy information shows for all events as expected.
- if I subscribe to the Google calendar from my personal copy of Outlook and personal Microsoft account, I get the exact same behavior.

I have tried running the exported ics through an online ics validator, but it balks at the file size. Running the last 450kb or so of the file through the validator doesn't show any errors, just some warnings about some lines being too long.

How can I see Outlook (or Outlook 365)'s logs or diagnostic info on calendar syncing? The Get-CalendarDiagnosticObjects cmdlet seems to be only for the native calendar hosted in Exchange, not for subscribed ones.

Comment: Also just noted that if I subscribe to the calendar from within the Outlook desktop app (my personal copy) it works fine. It's only when subscribing via OWA that it doesn't show all events. Subscribing from OWA is the only way supported by my company, which doesn't allow new pst creation.